# Observe fileInput button click even when no file loaded in R shiny app

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyjs

I have a short and seemingly naive question :

How can I detect that `fileInput` button has been clicked, even if no file is selected ?

Indeed, I would like to do something in `observeEvent` when a `fileInput` button is clicked, even if no file is loaded (I skip the details, it is part of a bigger app). It sounds quite simple, but with the pieces of code I've tried, I was not able to achieve it, because the `observeEvent` is always triggered only if a file is actually selected in the modal window.

There is likely a javascript way to detect the button click or the closing of the modal window (but I am ignorant of js...) ?

If anyone could help, I would be very very very grateful !

```
library(shiny)
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui=(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("TEST"),
    mainPanel(
      fileInput("file", "Upload file")
    )
  )),
  server = (function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$file, {
      ### something to do when button clicked - even if no file loaded
      cat(paste0("clicked\n"))  ### this is printed only if file loaded !!!
    })

  })))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide an own `click` handler like this:

```r
library(shiny)

js <- HTML("
$(function() {
  $('.shiny-input-container .input-group-btn .btn').on('click', function() {
     const id = $(this).find('input[type=\"file\"]').attr('id');
     Shiny.setInputValue(id + '_click', Math.random());
  })    
})")

ui <-  fluidPage(
   singleton(tags$head(tags$script(js))),
   titlePanel("TEST"),
   mainPanel(
      fileInput("file", "Upload file")
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
   observeEvent(input$file_click, {
      cat(paste0("clicked\n")) 
   })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```